# Echo in file returns No such file or directory

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, echo

I'm wondering why my simple script doesn't work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
user_variable='$1'
echo "export USER_VAR=$user_variable" > ~$user_variable/.filename
```

When I launch the script I have this error :

```
./script.sh admin: line 3: ~admin/.filename: No such file or directory
```

Of course, the directory for **~admin** exists:

```
~ # cd ~admin
/share/homes/admin #
```

And if I test this kind of command directly in command-line, it works:

```
# echo "test" > ~admin/.filetest
#
```

So why my echo command doesn't work in script file ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `bash(1)`:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter,
>   variable and arithmetic expansion and command substitution
>   (done in a left-to-right fashion), word splitting, and pathname expansion.

I.e., it does tilde expansion before variable expansion, so it doesn’t replace `$user_variable`
with `$1` (which, I assume, is “`admin`”) until after it has tried and failed to process the `~` –
because it is looking for a user named “`$user_variable`” rather than a user named “`admin`”.

Comment: You right ! If I use directly `/share/homes/$user_variable` instead of `~$user_variable` it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The ordering of expansions here does not stop you from using the variable according to your original intention. Usually **eval** can help when it comes to dynamic commands.

eval "echo \"export USER_VAR=$user_variable\" > ~$user_variable/.filename"